# Getting text to move over to a new Column

Tags: css

I am trying to get the text in the footer area Location & Hours to create two columns for each office. I tried to float it to the left with a height setting but it's not creating two columns. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

You can find the site here...

http://jsfiddle.net/ggJvM/

** Fiddle might be down **

I am looking to have both office and hours in there own columns.

Here is an area of the script and css i'm having problems with.

```
<div id="footer"><div class="content">
        <ul class="left">
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="default.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="practiceareas.php">PRACTICE AREAS</a></li>
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="attorneyprofiles.php">ATTORNEY PROFILES</a></li>
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="blog.php">BLOG</a></li>
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="locations.php">LOCATIONS &amp; HOURS</a></li>
            <li class="Footerbullets"><a href="contactus.php">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="center">
            <li class="Footerbullets">CURRENT NEWS</li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="Footerbullets">LOCATION &amp; HOURS</li>
            <li style="padding:3px 0 3px 25px;">Atlantic County Office:</strong><br>
    210 New Road, Suite 12<br>
    Linwood Greene<br>
    Linwood, New Jersey 08221<br>
    Phone: (609) 601-8677<br>
    Fax: (609) 601-8577<br><br>

    <strong>Office Hours:</strong><br>
    Monday - Friday: 08:30 AM-5:00 PM<br>
    Saturday: 10:00 AM-12:30 PM<br>
    Other hours by appointment<br />
     <br />
    <strong>Camden County Office:</strong><br>
    1939 Route 70 East, Suite 100<br>
    Cherry Hill, New Jersey 08003<br>
    Phone:(856) 874-0555<br>
    Fax: (856) 874-9683<br><br>

    <strong>Office Hours:</strong><br>
    Monday - Friday: 08:30 AM-5:00 PM<br>
          Saturday: 10:00 AM-12:30 PM<br>
         Other hours by appointment</li>
        </ul>
     </div></div>
```

**Here is part of the CSS for that area**

```
#footer .content {
border-bottom: 1px #fff dotted;
border-top: 1px #fff dotted;
width: 960px;
height: 135px;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
color:#FFF;
}
#footer ul{
float: left;
width: 319px;
height: 135px;
border-right: 1px #fff dotted;
color:#FFF;
 }
#footer ul:last-child {
border-right: none;
}

#footer {
background: #4D1516;
margin-top: -200px;
z-index: 1;
position:relative;
padding-top: 220px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
color:#FFF;
font-weight:bolder;
}

div#footer ul li a{
color : #115EAC;
background-color : transparent;
text-decoration : none;
color:#FFF;
}
 div#footer ul li a:hover{
text-decoration : underline;
}
.Footerbullets{
padding:3px 0 3px 25px;
background-image:url(http://www.gdisinc.com/barker/images/menubar/footer_bullet.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.Footerbullets a:link {
   color:#FFF;
 }
div#footer ul li.Footerbullets a:hover {
    color:#FF0;
 }

 /* Footer column sizes. */
#footer ul.left {
width: 20%;
 }

 #footer ul.center {
width: 40%;
 }

 #footer ul.right {
float: left;
width: 37%;
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason why we expect questions to be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/ggJvM/1/ ?

CSS:

```
.locationHours{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.locationHours>div{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
#footer .content,#footer ul{
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li class="locationHours">
    <div>
        <strong>Atlantic County Office:</strong><br>
        210 New Road, Suite 12<br>
        Linwood Greene<br>
        Linwood, New Jersey 08221<br>
        Phone: (609) 601-8677<br>
        Fax: (609) 601-8577<br><br>

        <strong>Office Hours:</strong><br>
        Monday - Friday: 08:30 AM-5:00 PM<br>
        Saturday: 10:00 AM-12:30 PM<br>
        Other hours by appointment<br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>Camden County Office:</strong><br>
        1939 Route 70 East, Suite 100<br>
        Cherry Hill, New Jersey 08003<br>
        Phone:(856) 874-0555<br>
        Fax: (856) 874-9683<br><br>

        <strong>Office Hours:</strong><br>
        Monday - Friday: 08:30 AM-5:00 PM<br>
        Saturday: 10:00 AM-12:30 PM<br>
                    Other hours by appointment
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got both offices in one List Item. Separate them by closing out the LI and opening a new one.

```
...
Other hours by appointment
</li><li>
<strong>Camden County Office:</strong>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use `float` property. It mess up the website in special rare conditions.
you can use a html **table** structure  or put them inside some *div* s with `display:inline-blok`.
see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dariushvb2010/UQwaM/1/)

Comment: I don't understand why there is that script in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the fiddle... the site might be down. But at a guess, have you specified a width as well? You'll need a width, or the ul will take up the whole area.

Comment: Yes, I have a width in there. Is the site not loading? http://jsfiddle.net/ggJvM/

Comment: I updated the question with the area of code having problems with. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Ok, it's because uls have a default padding value of 40px. so you either need to zero the padding, adjust your widths accordingly, or put containing divs around your lists and put the float/width on those :)